# TChartSeries.onClick trouble

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe4

I'm working with teechart and delphi XE4. I think my problem is pretty basic but, I can't find a solution.

In a short example, I have a TChartSeries with an event handler for the OnCLick event. 
In my code for event handling, I do the following:

```
if Button=mbRight then
begin
  clkSerie:=Sender;
  clkValue:=ValueIndex;
  GetCursorPos(P);
  pm1.Popup(P.X,p.Y);
end;
```

Then, in pm1.MyAction.OnClick

```
st:=InputBox('Agregar nota','Ingrese texto','');
if st<>'' then
begin
  clkserie.Marks.Item[clkValue].Text.Clear;
  clkserie.Marks.Item[clkValue].Text.Add(st);
  clkserie.Marks.Item[clkValue].Visible:=True;
end;
```

It works OK, with the only problem that, when I get out of this procedure, back in my chart with no popup menu or inputbox, I'm in "panning" status, it seems to be that the chart doesn't see my MOUSE_UP event.

I tried to simulate mouse clicks with `mouse_event()` and didn't worked. 
The only thing that worked is disabling panning for the chart, but I wouldn't like to take that way. I know there has to be a solution other than that.

I'll keep on trying and reading about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either the popup menu or the modal `InputBox` eat the mouse up message. Instead of showing the popup directly from your `OnClick` event handler, try only posting a custom message to your form and do the processing in its message hander (ie. delayed after mouse up has been processed).

Comment: I tried the following

`if Button=mbRight then
  begin
    clkSerie:=Sender;
    clkValue:=ValueIndex;
    GetCursorPos(P);
    PostMessage(Self.Handle,WM_SERIE_CLICK,0,0);
  end;
`
and, in message handler

 `SleepEx(200,false);
  pm1.Popup(P.X,p.Y);`

with the same result.

Answer (score 5):

Set `Chart1.CancelMouse := True` after click processing to stop the chart to initiate the default panning mode.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solves the opening question.